# The meaning of "slipping" in the text

Tags: greek

In the preface to the English Greek Lexicon of Liddell and Scott (LSJ) mention an article by Professor Diels published in the Neue Jahrbücher in 1905, in which Diels says:

“Any one who bears in mind the bulk of Greek literature, which is at least 10 times as great [as that of Latin], its dialectical variations, its incredible wealth of forms, the obstinate persistence of the classical speech for thousands of years down to the fall of Constantinople, or, if you will, until the present day: who knows, moreover, **that the editions of almost all the Greek classics are entirely unsuited for the purposes of *slipping***, that for many important writers no critical editions whatever exist: and who considers the state of our collections of fragments and special Lexica, will see that at the present time all the bases upon which a Greek Thesaurus could be erected are lacking.

What does ***slipping*** mean in the sentence “that the editions of almost all the Greek classics are entirely unsuited for the purposes of **slipping**”?

Answer (score 1):

"slipping" refers to the lexicographical practice of placing each illustrative quotation ("attestation" of a word's use) on a separate slip of paper.  The slips would be physically filed under the headword. When creating the entry for the word, the editorial staff of the dictionary would review the slips to get a sense of the range of meanings and, when possible, the word's semantic development over time.